# Getting a 'Type Error' When Iterating Through a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I am getting the following error:

> Can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

It is happening on this line:

```
if new_animal != animals[i]
```

Why is this happening?

```
animals = ['rhino', 'giraffe', 'cat', 'dolphin', 'turtle']

puts 'Enter the new animal:'
new_animal = gets.chomp

empty_array = []

animals.each do |i|
  if new_animal != animals[i]
    empty_array << i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`animals.each do |i|` is not doing what you think it does.  `i` then is the actual strings (animal names). So if you iterate through and use an animal name as an array accessor in `animals[i]` it is not an integer and cannot be converted to one.

```
animals.each do |animal|
    empty_array << animal if new_animal != animal
end
```

is the correct way to do it.

In Ruby if you want an iterator integer, you can do `each_index` and that will give you the integer position.  `each_index` is not used too much in Ruby though, that is why I refactored your code to what I posted.

Or you can just make it one line of code and do:

```
animals.index(new_animal)
```

which will return nil if it is not in the array or the fixnum position if it is in the array

Answer (score 1):

Michael got it right... when you run this code

```
animals = ['rhino', 'giraffe', 'cat', 'dolphin', 'turtle']
animals.each {|i| puts i}
```

you get:

```
rhino
giraffe
cat
dolphin
turtle
```

so "i" does not refer to what you expect it to refer to...